# Force spring to use JAXB for requestBody instead of Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson

We have a single endpoint Spring Boot application that produces and consumes XML. In the application, we use JAXB with a custom bindings.xjb file. We have the schema location of our XSD files from with we generate POJO classes. Unfortunately, we need to add library jackson-dataformat-xml (we are sure it's because of Jackson because we removed that lib and added Jackson to pom.xml as a proof) and since that our request body contains an object, but nested object inside of it is null. How can we force Spring Boot to use JAXB?

Comment: See [7.1.2. HttpMessageConverters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-web-applications.spring-mvc.message-converters)

Comment: Wooh, perfect! I added it as 
   `     @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        HttpMessageConverter<?> additional = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
        return new HttpMessageConverters(additional);
    } ` 
and works perfect. thanks!